# I am running this python code in windows powershell to convert a binary to decimal.I am expecting 13 as answer but getting 733

Tags: python

This is the code that I am running:

```
B = '1101' 
I = 0 
while B:     
    I = I * 2 +ord(B[0])
    B = B[1:] 
print I
```

Comment: `ord('1')` isn't `1`.

Comment: Why don't you just do `int(B[0])`?

Comment: silly me.Thank you.

Comment: `ord` usage should be `(ord(X) - ord('0'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you're expecting 33 but I can explain what's happening!

ord('1') (the string representation of 1) maps to 49, while ord('0') maps to 48. Switching `ord` to `int` should fix your answer.

So for each iteration of the loop (of which there are 4) you get
49
147
342
733.

Does that make sense?

Comment: got it. Thanks ! should have known that ord('1') isn't 1.

Comment: No worries! Using the python interpreter (run `python` from command line) can be a super helpful way to test little things like that.